# Use custom DI provider in DotNetCore 3.1 Worker Service?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, worker

Does anyone know how to set up a custom DI provider (such as Castle Windsor) in a DotNetCore Worker Service?  I've seen info on how to do it for ASP.NET apps, but all the examples talk about modifying Startup.cs, which does not exist in the Worker Service template.

Comment: IHostBuilder in Program.cs provides every extension point Startup class does. In fact there's nothing special about Startup class, it just offers you a couple of callbacks, which you can set with IHostBuilder directly.

Comment: @abdusco - Thanks!  I'm having trouble finding helpful info about all this beyond the obvious and obligatory "happy path" tutorials.  Any info links would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, I'll post an example with AutoFac, because Castle Windsor doesn't seem to support modern .NET Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using custom dependency injection container in a .NET Core Worker project

Castle Windsor doesn't support recent .NET Core versions, so I'll use Autofac as an example.

When you start a new `worker` project, you'll have a Program class like this

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` gives you an `IHostBuilder`, which has necessary methods to extend or replace the DI container. We're using Autofac, so let's install it:

```
dotnet add package Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

Then introduce it to our host. Here `ContainerBuilder` comes from Autofac assembly.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        // use autofac
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        // configure autofac di container
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((hostContext, container) =>
        {
            // hostcontext gives you access to config & environment
            // hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ApiKeys");
            // hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()

            // auto register all classes in the assembly
            container
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        })
        // configure microsoft di container
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            // let autofac register this service
            // services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

Now let's create a service. `IJob` interface here is unnecessary, it's just there to show Autofac's capabilities:

```cs
internal interface IJob
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

internal class WarmUpCaches : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<WarmUpCaches> _logger;

    public WarmUpCaches(ILogger<WarmUpCaches> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Warming up caches");
        var steps = 5;
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && --steps > 0)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("working...");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Done");
    }
}
```

Now let's use this service inside the background service:

```cs
class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IJob _job;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IJob job)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _job = job;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _job.ExecuteAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

When we run the app, it logs:

```
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      Warming up caches
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      working...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\...\CustomDiExample
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      working...
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      working...
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      working...
info: CustomDiExample.WarmUpCaches[0]
      Done
```

### Consuming services without using a background service

If the application doesn't need to keep working, we can do without a `BackgroundService`.

We need to modify the `Main` method and expose the `IHost` instance. We can resolve any service from the container using `IHost.Services`.

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    // stop the application with Ctrl+C, SIGINT, SIGTERM
    var lifetime = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();
    var cancellationToken = lifetime.ApplicationStopping;

    var job = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJob>();
    await job.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

### References

- https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html?highlight=AutofacServiceProviderFactory#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.useserviceproviderfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Thanks for this extensive info. It appears that this project (https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter) allows  Castle Windsor to perform the same functions as AutoFac in your example.  I've made a gist that demonstrates what I think is the proper use of it -- https://gist.github.com/jamie-tillman/0ff425e34f613b2d9fa4ade26980e5eb 
At least it *seems* to be using Windsor for the DI.  Hard to tell.  Does `ConfigureServices` automatically use the registered DI?

Comment: https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter that kind of usage is deprecated. That's what I was referring to with _"Castle Windsor doesn't support recent .NET Core versions"_. Recent versions don't want you to return an `IServiceProvider` from `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

Comment: _Does ConfigureServices automatically use the registered DI?_ I'd guess so. Try registering a class in `ConfigureContainer`, then registering another in `ConfigureServices` with longer overload. Try resolving the class registered in `ConfigureContainer`. `services.AddTransient<MyType>(serviceProvider => return new MyType(serviceProvider.GetService<AServiceRegisteredInConfigureContainer>()))`

Comment: See this for the modern usage: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/net-dependency-extension.md

Comment: Thanks for the link to "modern usage".  Will dig into that.  I was aware of the Startup.ConfigureServices return value being deprecated, but that library I referenced appears to provide other bridge classes that helped with the gist I created.  Obviously the Startup.ConfigureServices thing was focused on ASP.NET, which I'm not working with, per the original question.  Maybe your referenced info will make that library I found unnecessary.